# Firebase firestore db orderBy document id

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I need to retrieve a big amount of data.

I'm trying to order by 'id'. But the query returns an empty collection. if remove orderBy('id') it works properly.
How to sort by document id?

```
mQuery = docRef.orderBy('id')
              .limit(bulk_size)
                .get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `.orderBy('id')` it means that you trying to order the documents that you get from Firestore according to a field called `id`. If you want to order the documents according to the document ID, then please use:

```
mQuery = docRef.orderBy(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId())
               .limit(bulk_size)
               .get();
```